# Controls are not being displayed in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I copied my source code files for the next version of my app. When I open the copied project in Xcode, the controls are hidden and are not being displayed in viewcontrols in storyboard, but when I am running, all controls are appearing in simulator and device.

I am using Xcode 6.4

Comment: are you talking about elemtns are hidden when you opened your storyboard? post a screenshot of it for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it height and width to its original which was it before.

See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Oud.jpg